# Generate repeat sequence in calendar table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sequence, repeat

I'm generating a calendar table, how do I generate repeat sequence as below. Thanks.

```
dt                   |id_1|id_2  
2013-01-01 00:00:00       |1|              3            
2013-01-01 01:00:00       |1|              3         
2013-01-01 02:00:00       |1|              3    
2013-01-01 03:00:00       |2|              3       
2013-01-01 04:00:00       |2|              3          
2013-01-01 05:00:00       |2|              4         
2013-01-01 06:00:00       |3|              4
```

sequence of id_1 will be 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3,....until 6,6,6, then restarts at 1,1,1,..

and sequence of id_2 will start at 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, ... until 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, then restarts at 1, 1, 1, 1, 1....

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do this with basic arithmetic. The answer is to convert the date and hour to number of hours since midnight, 1/1/2013, and then convert these to series using integer division and modulo operator.  The result is something like:

```
select (((date(dt) - date('2013-01-01))*24 + hour(dt)) div 3) mod 5) + 1 as id_1,
       (2+(((date(dt) - date('2013-01-01))*24 + hour(dt)) div 5) mod 9) + 1 as id_2
```

Comment: right now, all id_1 and ide_2 are null, I want to start filling from the first row, thanks!